# Angular 16 Prerender Exclude Node Module

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular 16 Application. The team wants the Angular prerender functionality.
On one page we have integrated Ngx-Konva for Canvas functionality.
For Ngx Konva we have the dependencies:

```
"konva": "^9.3.3",
"ngx-konva": "^16.1.0",
```

All modules are standalone and lazy loaded. We have also added a directive to prevent `SSR`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ssrExclude]'
})
export class SSRExcludeDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private readonly _templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private readonly _platformId: Object
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformServer(this._platformId)) {
      this._viewContainer.clear();
    } else {
      this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._templateRef);
    }
  }}
```

angular.json:

```
    "prerender": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
      "options": {
        "routes": [
          "/"
        ],
        "guessRoutes": false
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:production",
          "serverTarget": "app:server:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:development",
          "serverTarget": "app:server:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
```

If we run `ng run app:prerender` we get the following error:

```
./node_modules/konva/lib/index-node.js:7:15-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: 
Can't resolve 'canvas' in ...
Did you mean './canvas'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within 
module directories (***).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 
'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current 
directory too.
```

What can we do, to exclude the Konva lib?